# Taking data from graph api with node

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to connect with the facebook api to be able to get a feed of a certain page.

But I'm getting an access token error

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"DrEySZsEOOA"}}
```

I'm trying this:
Facebook.js:

```
var https = require('https');
exports.get = function(accessToken, apiPath, callback) {
    var options = {
        host: 'graph.facebook.com',
        port: 443,
        path: apiPath + '?access_token=' + accessToken,
        method: 'GET'
    };
     var buffer = '';
    var request = https.get(options, function(result){
        result.setEncoding('utf8');
        result.on('data', function(chunk){
            buffer += chunk;
        });
        result.on('end', function(){
            callback(buffer);
        });
    });
    request.on('error', function(e){
        console.log('error from facebook.get(): '
                     + e.message);
    });

    request.end();
}
```

app.js:

```
var facebook = require('./facebook');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);


facebook.get('121212', '/feed/', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});

server.listen(9999);
```

Yes, I passed the right token. I just modified it for obvious reasons hahaha

Would anyone have an idea or an example?

Thank you all

Comment: Did you set authentication properly https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login ?

Comment: Thank you,

I'll try and come back with news. sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

This would be the API call: https://graph.facebook.com/feed?access_token=xxx

...which is missing something important: the ID of a User, Page or Group.

For example: https://graph.facebook.com/[page-id]/feed?access_token=xxx

Keep in mind that you need different Tokens and permissions if it is about a User, Page or Group.

Comment: Thank you,

I'll try and come back with news. sorry for the delay